# Difference between JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME?

Tags: java

In which scenario we go for the `JRE_HOME`? If I have not mention `JRE_HOME` what will happen?

Answer (score 5):

- Variable `JRE_HOME` is used for `JRE` (Java Runtime Environment). It's the Java Virtual Machine where Java programs run on. My example of `%JRE_HOME%`: `C:\Dev\jre1.8.0_65`
- Variable `JAVA_HOME` is used for `JDK` (Java Development Kit). It's the development kit to create and compile programs in Java. My example of `%JAVA_HOME%`: `C:\Dev\jdk1.8.0_65`

Shortly you use `JRE` in case you care of running programs only. On the other hand developing Java programs requires `JDK`.

Comment: Ya, We have to give the specified directory path, But When to use JRE_Home is my question

Comment: Edited, I have explained the difference and the case of use.